# Ways to share Pytorch model without revealing architecture?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, deployment, serialisation

We are trying to give a model to collaborators but would like to protect the IP. What are some ways to encrypt/hide/compile the definition when sharing a trained model?

Answer (score 1):

One way to protect the IP of a trained model is to put the model behind an API. Give only limited API end-point access.

Comment: Yes, something like docker. I did think of that one. Is there no way to "compile" a model to something like a binary?